# Using tiles to create a new document in SharePoint 2013

Tags: document, tiles

I would like to add a tile to the Home page which will allow the user to open up the form to add a new document rather than simply accessing the Document Library.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just copy the link from the "New Button" in your library and add that to the tile. Should work.

Comment: Apparently the add a file screen needs to be in a dialog box rather than maximised which is what happens with this method.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Create Promoted link list to get tiles view .

Reference :[Create Promoted link](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-promoted-links-list-app-part-1)

1. Click on New document -->When upload form is open, right click on it and then click properties. You will get the URL in properties window.
2. Add that URL in Promoted list item
3. Add this Promoted link list in home page as a webpart

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.  The issue is that when they click on New Document, they need to add a file first and then the new document form appears.  The add a file dialog box comes up when I add the URL for it but once I add the file, it produces a message which states that it is working on it but nothing happens.